# AWS CloudWatch alarm for ELB HealthyHostCount or UnhealthyHostCount

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I have set up two EC2 instances in an Auto Scaling Group behind an application load balancer. I want to set up an alarm in Cloud Watch to get notification when both EC2 insatnces are `unhealthy` .

What metric should I use in CloudWatch?

Either `HealthyHostCount >= 0 or UnhealthyHostCount <=1 or UnhealthyHostCount >=0`

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would use `UnhealthyHostCount >=0` to let you know that at least one of your instances is unhealthy and I'd use `HealthyHostCount < minimum ASG count` to make sure that your instances are not missing from the ELB. Make sure to consider any timings of events whereby you might deregister/register instances.

Comment: I don't know much about AWS, but `UnhealthyHostCount >=0` sounds like you would get a notification if 0 or more hosts are unhealthy (greater than or equal to symbol?).